# Deploying Next.Js App to Azure Results in BadRequest Reason: The size of the function content was too large

Tags: azure, next.js, azure-static-web-app, azure-static-website-hosting

I have a next.js app that I am trying to deploy to Azure using GitHub Actions. - But the deployment failes with the following error.

> The content server has rejected the request with: BadRequest Reason:
> The size of the function content was too large. The limit for this
> Static Web App is 104857600 bytes.

When I run npm run build on my local machine the output folder which is ".next" ends up being 27mb so I don't understand why I am getting this error.

Also the error message says **"The limit for this Static Web App is 104857600 bytes"**

However when I created the static app in azure, I have selected the standard hosting plan. Which according the portal allows 500MB, even the free hosting plan allows a size of 250MB.

So why does the error message say the limit for this static Web App is 104857600 bytes which converts to 104MB?

[image]

So what am I missing here?

Comment: Could you please share your `GitHub code Repository` ?

Comment: Having exactly the same issue - did you come to any solution here?

Comment: Change in next.config.js to provide standalone output helped for my case and app is now deploying properly using Azure static web apps
`output: "standalone"`

Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/deploy-nextjs-hybrid#enable-standalone-feature